# koGrid causing "Mixed Content" warning in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer, knockout.js, internet-explorer-7, kogrid

koGrid is causing IE7 to display its "Mixed Content" warning.

What is causing this? Is there a fix?

http://jsfiddle.net/3uyaK/1/

```
<div data-bind="koGrid: { data: myObservableArray }"></div>

var vm = {
  myObservableArray: ko.observableArray([{id:1, name:"a"}, {id:2, name:"b"}])
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Comment: I'm afraid IE7 is just not supported: https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/KoGrid/issues/162

Comment: @nemesv, disappointing, but that answer is good enough for me.

Comment: @nemesv, want to make that comment an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is causing this? Is there a fix?

Maybe there is a workaround for this problem, but I wouldn't expect an official fix...

Because **IE7 is not supported** by koGrid.

From the closed [github issue #162](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/KoGrid/issues/162):

> timothyswt commented
>   Ie7 is not supported.